# Are there highway tolls between Vienna and Salzburg?

Tags: car-rentals, austria, vignettes

I plan to rent a car in Vienna and drive to Salzburg and back.

[Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Salzburg,+Austria/Vienna,+Austria/@47.763146,16.9785999,7z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47769adda908d4b1:0xc1e183a1412af73d!2m2!1d13.05501!2d47.80949!1m5!1m1!1s0x476d079e5136ca9f:0xfdc2e58a51a25b46!2m2!1d16.3738189!2d48.2081743!3e0) suggests driving through A1 road but indicates

> This route has tolls.

I know that in Austria one needs to buy a [toll sticker](https://www.austria.info/en/service-and-facts/getting-there-around/by-car/vignette), in order to drive the highways.

1. Are there additional tolls for driving the A1? Or the sticker is the only toll for such a drive?
2. Can I assume that a car rented in Vienna will already be with the sticker, or this is something I will need to buy?

Comment: I expect the car to already have a toll sticker as those are not supposed to be transferable and are therefore hard to remove. You should ask the rental company.

Comment: Unless you actually need the car for something on either end, it might be way easier to take a train. That route is the most busy train route in Austria, and has multiple trains every hour.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually a few tunnels and mountain passes in Austria where you have to pay additional toll, but between Vienna and Salzburg, the regular toll sticker will cover everything.

Rental cars in Austria will at least from the larger chains usually already come with toll paid. I see now that Sixt guarantees that cars rented in Austria have toll paid in advance, other rental companies are more vague and with the cheaper budget rental companies, I would not be quite sure what to expect. Be aware though, that the toll can now also be paid and connected to the car's registration number without having the physical sticker attached to the wind shield. If the rental car doesn't have a sticker, the autobahn toll may still have been paid.

You can use [Asfinag Evidenz](https://evidenz.asfinag.at/en/) to check if your car already has a valid digital toll sticker. Enter the registration by selecting Austria and the registration number of the car in format W-12345A.